# Overriding CSS Reset with the Univeral Selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-reset

I have a reset (Eric Meyer's Reset) which sets the font, then I load my stylesheet on top of this, in which I want to set the font globally using the universal selector

But although in my SASS the universal selector is loaded **after** the reset, the reset is taking precedence. (Please see attached screenshot from devtools)

I know this is to do with specificity, but I thought the universal selector would act as a wildcard. Why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The universal selector * has no specificity value.  Essentially anything and everything takes precedence over it.

Via MDN:

> The following list of selector types is by increasing specificity:
>
> Universal selectors (e.g., *)
>
> Type selectors (e.g., h1)
>
> Class selectors (e.g., .example)
>
> Attributes selectors (e.g., [type="radio"])
>
> Pseudo-classes (e.g., :hover)
>
> ID selectors (e.g., #example)
>
> Inline style (e.g., style="font-weight:bold")

and of course !important overrides all the above, but also does not have a specificity value.

A good source for additional information can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Thank you, So what is the "best" method of setting the font globally then, (in *my* stylesheet, without touching the reset) ? I could have a compound selector with all the tags (like in the reset), but that seems overkill.

Comment: generally on the body element, since fonts inherit. `html{font-size:100%;font-family:sans-serif;} body{font-size:1em; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;}`